# Using "any" with countable nouns in question forms

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, singular-vs-plural

Which ones are grammatically correct out of the following sentences:

> Do you know **any** famous **person**?
>
> Do you know **any** famous **people**?
>
> Do you do **any** physical **activity** for staying in shape?
>
> Do you do **any** physical **activities** for staying in shape?

I am not sure but I remember reading that we should use plural forms with *any* in affirmative sentences. If we accept this rule as correct, can we apply this rule to questions in which the word *any* is used?

Comment: The activity/activities sentences need a remark: activity has two usages, one as a countable noun, and one as the other kind (like water or sand).  Therefore, although you'd have to try pretty hard to construct a situation where you could use your Sentence #1, your Sentence #3 AND your Sentence #4 are both good.

Comment: `the other kind` = `uncountable`? :)

Answer (score 2):

While in some contexts, "know any famous person" or "do any physical activity" *could* be used, the non-standard structure would be being used as emphasis, and in dialogue. ("Okay, we've got to find someone who'll endorse our product. Joe knows a rockstar, and Jane knows three politicians and a movie star. How about you, Chris? Do you know *any* famous person?")

But even in such contrived circumstances, it would not be *incorrect* to use the plural forms, and would sound more natural in general, so I'd advise using them by default. I can't think of many contexts which pair "any" with a singular noun.

(One possible exception: any place. E.g., "Is there any place that's not closed on Thanksgiving? We don't have any power to cook at home!")

Comment: Thank you for your answer.It just came to mind that can we say that if we expect/want more than one we should use plural form?

Comment: Yes, sort of. In the case of your third example, "physical activity" can be either specific or general. It can refer to a specific activity or to activity in general (as opposed to no activity at all). So this particular usage is correct, even though "activity" is technically single.

Comment: You confused me! Which **IS** the correct form?